# How can I change the date format in a Search Kit result?

Tags: smarty, dates, searchkit, formatting

I have a Search Kit search that shows the date like this: `November 1st, 2012 12:00 AM`.  I want to reformat this as `11/01/22`.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 10):

- You must be on CiviCRM 5.47+ to have the "Use Smarty in Search Kit rewrites" feature.
- Create a Search Display based on your search - e.g. **Add » Table** using the **Add** button in the left pane.
- Find your date field and check the **Rewrite** box.  You'll see a token that represents your date, e.g. `[receive_date]`.
- Change the rewrite value to the following.  Substitute your token for `[receive_date]` below.

```
{"[receive_date]"|date_format:"%D"}
```

A full list of date formatting options is available in the [Smarty date_format documentation](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.date.format.tpl).

(Ignore the older rewrite text in the screenshot, the value above is the improved version!)

[image]

Comment: 0

Do you have to enable the smarty option? We have tried the above but all the dates are coming out as todays date in the output

Olly

Comment: @OliverGibson There's nothing you need to set.  I just recreated this on a brand new Civi and took a screenshot, which I added to the answer.  Hopefully this clears things up?  If not, hit me up on chat (@junglebird)